# Correlation coefficient between two data sets having points of different dimensions

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, python, numpy

I have a dataset in which one side there are vectors of dimension 3 and other side is a real number corresponding to each vector. Now I need to find the correlation coefficient between the two set. Can anyone please suggest me some good method (preferably having a in built function in python) to calculate the correlation between those two dataset? I am very new statistics, so don't have much knowledge. I viewed the  Kendall tau in built function in python but it says that if one of the variable is 2-D matrix (basically a set of vectors) then it will convert it to 1_D which in my opinion will not give the required result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [multiple correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correlation). In short, just like in simple regression correlation ($r$) is the square root of the coefficient of determination ($R^2$), in multiple regression you can also use the square root of $R^2$ as multiple coefficient of correlation.

In most statistical packages $R^2$ is computed when performing multiple regression. Then, you just need to perform multiple regression or your real variable using the components of your vector variable as predictors, extract $R^2$ and take its square root.

I never tried it but in Python it can be done with Numpy.

Comment: Thanks @pere. It really helped. But still I am facing the problem of finding the value of p in such cases. I have successfully calculated the correlation coefficient but there nobody mentioned anything about how to calculate p.

Comment: That's the F-test value for the whole model. R and most statistical packages compute it by default when computing regression. I haven't checked numpy, but I would expect it to perform F-test, too.

Comment: I used the method mentioned on "multiple correlation" wiki page that you mentioned to calculate correlation coefficient. There was no proper inbuilt function I guess so implemented it. But there was nothing p value on the page I will try to take a look at how to perform the t-test.

Comment: The p-value is that of the F-test. As said, I never tried in Python, but I would check http://connor-johnson.com/2014/02/18/linear-regression-with-python/ . There is some information about F-test and its p-value.